# PHP Ajax javascript looping through table with input fields

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can i get specific input values of each row when i click the button using ajax javascript. here is my code

here is my example of getting the data from database dynamically with input fields and button individually

```
<div style="width:100%; min-height:275px;">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tablelist">
                    <form  action=""  method="get" name="formwebservice">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="pgLoading">
                                <table style="border:1px solid #FF00A6; border-top:none;" class="tablelisttable" 
                                       border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr class="tablelisttr">
                                        <td>Branch ID</td>
                                        <td>Branch Code</td>
                                        <td>Branch Name</td> 
                                        <td>Last Sync Date</td>
                                        <td>Start Date</td>
                                        <td>End Date</td>
                                        <td>Synchronization</td>
                                        <td></td> 
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php 
                                        $query_branch="SELECT * FROM Branch";
                                        $query_branch_result=mysqli_query($con,$query_branch) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_branch_result)) {
                                                echo "<tr class='listtr' align='center'>
                                                          <td>".$row['BranchID']."</td>
                                                          <td>".$row['BranchCode']."</td>
                                                          <td>".$row['BranchName']."</td>
                                                          <td>2018-04-14 05:39:57</td>
                                                          <td><input type='text' name='startdate'> </td>
                                                          <td><input type='text' name='enddate'></td>
                                                          <td><input type='button' name='sync' value='Synchronize'></td>
                                                          <td>0/0</td>
                                                      </tr>";
                                        }
                                     ?>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
                </table>
            </div>
```

index.js

```
 $(function(){

    $('[name=sync]').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type        :   "get",
            data        :   $('[name=formwebservice]').serialize(),
            url         :   "save.php",
            success     :   function(data){
                $('.loader').html('&nbsp;');
                $('.pgLoading').html(data).hide().fadeIn('slow');

            },
            beforeSend  :   function(){
                $('.loader').html('Loading... Please wait...').hide().fadeIn();
            }
        });

    }); });
```

save.php

```
if(isset($_GET['startdate']) && isset($_GET['enddate'])) {

$StartDate=$_GET['startdate'];
$EndDate=$_GET['enddate'];

echo $StartDate;
echo $EndDate;
}else{
echo "NO DATA INPUT";
}
```

my problem is the $_GET['startdate'] and $_GET['enddate'] is not set so im always getting no data input.

Comment: Your `save.php` looks to be missing a `isset` before the `enddate` test.

Comment: i see i edit it but now my problem is im not getting the right value of row that i click

Comment: you are using `ajax get`,be careful the result may be cached

Comment: i am missing the part where you add the get vars to your `url: save.php`